# how to resize a panel?

Tags: modeling

The panel surrounded with the red line (I don't know its name) has become very small. How can I resize it? [image]

Comment: Numpad + key while the mouse cursor is over this panel to zoom in. Or Home key to restore it to default size.

Comment: That's called Last Operator panel. Available for opening by `F6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This panel can be resized by dragging. Hover with the mouse over the line between the upper and lower part until the mouse pointer turns into a black two ended arrow. Then click and drag up or down. You can even hide the Operator panel completely. Then you will see a little plus sign. Which you can click to reveal the panel again.

[image]

Comment: actually the fonts of thsi panel have bcome too small and I don't know how to bring them back to their normal size.

Comment: In this case move with the mouse over the panel and press Home key (german keyboard Pos1). This will reset the scale. To scale it bigger or smaller, hover with the mouse over the panel, hold down ctrl, hold down middle mouse button, and move the mouse up or down.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you intend "resize" as to gain more space availeble for that panel...

You need to put the mouse cursor at the top of it...  here

[image]

When the position is right you'll get a vertical up/down arrow that allows you to resize it (my screenshot tool doesn't get itso you see a regular pointer arrow there), like this:

[image]